# coldfusion 10 application server service not starting

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-administrator

I added in Coldfusion administrator => Java and jvm => JVM arguments  **-Dfile.encoding=UTF8** and application server service not starting.

Here is the error. So is there a way to undo what I have done.  Because there is no way access to the Administrator panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those, who would encounter the same problem,

open the `ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\jvm.config` file as you would see the JVM arguments which you have added. I deleted the `Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and service begin running again.